# How to tell a JDesktopPane to fill the entire screen of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdesktoppane

Any body please suggest the code How to tell a `JDesktopPane` to fill the entire screen of `JFrame` in Java `Netbeans IDE`.

Comment: You don't, you tell the `JFrame` to use the correct layout for the component based on your need. Please see [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the layout of your `JFrame` to `BorderLayout`.
2. Add your `JDesktopPane` to the `CENTER` area of your JFrame:

   ```
   JFrame f = new JFrame();
   f.setBounds(50, 50, 500, 400);
   f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
   JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
   f.add(desktopPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);        
   f.setVisible(true);
   ```

The magic is coming from how `BorderLayout` manages the layout of its children components. Anything is added to the `CENTER` area of `BorderLayout` will fill as much area as it can get from the its container.

If you want to maximize a `JInternalFrame` inside the `JDesktopPane`, you should call `setMaximum(true)` on it after it's added to the underlying `JDesktopPane`:

```
public class JDesktop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setBounds(50, 50, 500, 400);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JInternalFrame internalFrame1 = new JInternalFrame("Internal Frame 1", true, true, true, true);     
        internalFrame1.setSize(150, 150);
        internalFrame1.setVisible(true);        

        JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
        desktopPane.add(internalFrame1);
        try {
            internalFrame1.setMaximum(true);
        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        f.add(desktopPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Now that you got the idea it's not bad to know about the defaults. The default layout manager for `JFrame` is `BorderLayout` and when you add anything to a `JFrame` without specifying the constraint for the area, it will be added to the `CENTER` area. So you can omit these lines in you code:

```
f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

and you can add the `desktopPane` simply using this line:

```
f.add(desktopPane);
```

Comment: To be fair, `BorderLayout` is the default layout in a `JFrame`. And adding a component in a `BorderLayout` without specifying a constraint will use `BorderLayout.CENTER`. So `JFrame f = new JFrame(); f.add(desktopPane);` is enough.

Comment: @AxelH: Thanks for the hint. I know that as I work with it every day. I wrote those line there just for the emphasis on the concept of layout management in frames or other container and how `BorderLayout.CENTER` constraint will behave. Since the question asks about netbeans tools on any other window builder I just wanted him to go deeper about the concepts. But I will add your tip to my answer to add information about the default.